# Javascript cant append elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, append, element

I am getting some data from my server and I want to create element but this code is not  working please help me

```
var filelist=['dummy1','dummy2','etc']
    
      filelist.forEach(file=>{
    
      var newli=document.createElement("li")
      var newa=document.createElement("a")
      newa.innerHTML=file
      newa.setAttribute('href',file)
      newli.append(newa)
      
      box.append(newli)
    
      })
```

Note the box is a div in above code

Comment: consider creating a jsbin or the like and linking to it

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to create a runnable example here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There is no `append` method; you want [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Comment: code is not working? Can you share any log of error? plus how you are getting box element?

Comment: Open up your developer tools, read the error message in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this is working. One needs to assure that before the execution of any DOM accessing functionality, the former has to be ready/loaded.

```js
const fileNameList = ['dummy1', 'dummy2', 'etc'];
    
const box = document.getElementById('box');

fileNameList.forEach(fileName => {

  const newLi = document.createElement("li");
  const newA = document.createElement("a");

  newA.innerHTML = fileName;
  newA.setAttribute('href', fileName);

  newLi.append(newA);
  box.appendChild(newLi);
});
```

```html
<div id='box'>Your box</div>
```

Comment: @Lonely if it works then please accept the answer, and it is working by you and by me and on codepen also, so your friend have to check what type of environment he/she has.

Comment: Bro Its working now I didnt even change the code can you tell me why its not working at that time and now its working without doing any thing I really wanna know if everything fine then why it didnt work I even refreshed the page several time and reboot laptops please tell me

Comment: bro by me it works from the very first attempt, really I can not guess what was wrong at your side and why it was not working
Might be DOM was loading after code execution, you know my guess. But lets do a vote up now ;)

Comment: I want to tell you that my script works fine and your also can you explain me which should i use append or append child

Comment: I really recommend this:
https://dev.to/ibn_abubakre/append-vs-appendchild-a4m